# QMenu memory leak which everyone knows,but how to fix it?

Tags: qt

I have this code in a slot function.

```
QCursor cur=this->cursor();
QMenu* pRightKeyMenu=new QMenu(this);
pRightKeyMenu->popup(cur.pos());
```

When I click the right mouse key, it will be invoked. After that, I find that memory is going up up up... and never goes down. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `pRightKeyMenu` is leaking because you're not releasing it.

One possible solution is to reuse it, since, by your code, the created QMenu is always the same:

```
Widget::Widget()
{
    // ...
    this->pRightKeyMenu = new QMenu(this);
}

// Slot
void Widget::contextMenu()
{
    QCursor cur=this->cursor();
    this->pRightKeyMenu->popup(cur.pos());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also you could do:

```
QCursor cur=this->cursor();
QMenu* pRightKeyMenu=new QMenu(this);
connect(pRightKeyMenu, SIGNAL(aboutToHide()), pRightKeyMenu, SLOT(deleteLater()));;
pRightKeyMenu->popup(cur.pos());
```

Comment: This way looks promising for my case but it turns out that it results in segfaults sometimes. Looks like it's at least the case is when windows native modal dialog is triggered on action.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid any leak, add the QMenu as QScopedPointer to your class and instantiate the menu in the class constructor.

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
...
private:
  QScopedPointer<QMenu> _myMenu;
}

Widget::Widget()
{
...
  _myMenu.reset(new QMenu(this));
  _myMenu->addAction("Some menuitem..", this, SLOT(menuItemActivated()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
QMenu pRightKeyMenu;
pRightKeyMenu.exec(cur.pos());
```

Comment: pRightKeyMenu will be deleted when out of scope - you will not even see the popup

Comment: @killaclick `exec()` is a blocking operation so the menu won't go out of scope before it is closed.